# how to add class to all columns of a table in elm script

Tags: elm

The elm scripts gets a csv string `csv` from backend code. I want to create a table and **the class name of each cell should be the column name**.

The rows of the table can be obtained from `rows = String.split "\n" csv`. If I don't need to define classes, a table can be created by applying doubly nested `List.map` on `rows`. But in order to give class to each cell, I need to save the first element of row which contains the column (or class) names and pair it with each of the remaining rows. Since there is no for loop in elm, my strategy is to define a recursive function to create all `tr` elements and concatenate the `tr` elements using `List.map`. The input of this function is the first row called `names` and another row called `cols`. They are both `List String`. Each time it runs, it creates a `td` using the heads (from `List.head`) of the two Lists and then pass the remaining elements of the two lists (from `List.drop`) for recursion. But I couldn't concatenate the two returned components.

```
createRow names cols =
    case cols of
        [] -> text ""
        _ ->
            let
                c0 = (List.head cols)
                c = (List.drop 1 cols)
                n0 = (List.head names)
                n = (List.drop 1 names)
            in
                td [] [text <| toString <| c0]
                , createRow n c
```

What should I put in the `in` block? Or is there a better way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output of the function? You mention `tr`s in the description, but there are no `tr`s in the code, just a `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a recursive function, you need to pass the (partially-computed) result along, so that you can modify it in each call, and return it once you've finished recursing.  So that might look something like this:

```
createRow : List String -> List String -> List (Html msg) -> List (Html msg)
createRow names cols cells =
    case cols of 
        [] -> cells
        col :: remainingCols ->
            let
                name = 
                    names
                    |> List.head
                    |> Maybe.withDefault ""
                remainingNames = List.drop 1 names
                cell =
                    td [class name] [text col]
            in
            createRow remainingNames remaningCols (cells ++ [ cell ])
```

A couple of other notable changes here:

- I've used pattern matching to extract the head of the `cols` list from the rest (also called the tail)
- `List.head` returns a `Maybe a` (in this case, `a` is `String`), so I've added a call to `Maybe.withDefault`
- Since `cols` is a `List String`, you don't need to call `toString` and can pass it directly to `text`
- When you call this function for the first time, you'll pass in `[]` for the `cells` argument

Answer (score 4):

First I would suggest you don't parse the CSV manually. There are multiple CSV parsers available on the package manager so we can instead focus on what to do with the values.

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/periodic/elm-csv/latest/Csv
is an option, but they all give you a `Csv` type after parsing, which looks like this:

```
type alias Csv =
    { headers : List String
    , records : List (List String)
    }
```

As you have touched on, there are as many headers as there are values in each row (otherwise the CSV wouldn't be valid). Dropping/casing through recursion can get the job done, but we can be more declarative by relying on list operations to do the bulk of the work:

```
classTable : Csv -> Html msg
classTable csv =
    table []
        (csv.records |> List.map (tableRow csv.headers))


tableRow : List String -> List String -> Html msg
tableRow headers values =
    let
        insertNextCellInRow ( header, value ) row =
            td [ class header ] [ text value ] :: row
    in
    tr []
        (List.map2 Tuple.pair headers values
            |> List.foldr insertNextCellInRow []
        )
```

Note: `List.foldr` is recursive and serves the purpose of a loop in an imperative language ("for each item in this list, apply this function and collect the results in this other list"). It is however agnostic of the types of values passed to it and allows us to focus on transforming the values.